# How to create a geographical heat map in excel using Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to generate a heat map from given data. i Need to analyze where participants came from and how far they were from the event. i Am trying to visualize this in excel and so far have been unsuccessful.

So far I've tried creating each column into a Formula so that I could generate the map via a YouTube tutorial but haven't been able to get it to work. There are international Zip Codes which I feel might be throwing off the map.

I was attempting to use the `OFFSET` Function to make the data linear and more easier to analyze

```
 =OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers];[Country]];1;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1
```

Any suggestions on the best way to do this in excel? Or how to fix the code so it fits for the analysis. I'll post a bit of the data below.

```
"Customer Id","City","Region Code","Postal Code","Country","Product Membership Description"
"123","Jacksonville","FL","32256","United States","Metro Magazine;NEWS-MET-Express"
"456","HARTFORD","KY","423471178","United States","Government Fleet;Metro Magazine;Work Truck Magazine;NEWS-GF-Enews;NEWS-GF-EquipmentGuide;NEWS-GF-TopNews;NEWS-MET-Blogs;NEWS-MET-Express;NEWS-MET-Rail;NEWS-MET-Trending;Z3 Metro Transit Accessibility - 6193;NEWS-WT-Utility"
"789","TALLAHASSEE","FL","32301","United States","Metro Magazine;NEWS-MET-Express"
```

Comment: If you want to see *"how far they were from the event"*, you'll need to generate a column that has that information. I don't see that in your sample data.

Comment: Create a lookup table for the zip code v distance - can just be a 1 for closest or the actual mileage...

Answer (score 0):

So, just played with your data and set this up. You can expand as you wish, use the city or the region code or post code as you wish.

[image]

You can decide what distance data you want to use, perhaps circles of distance from your location may be interesting...